# Getting midnight timestamp value from specific timestamp

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I just want to calculate the midnight value for the timestamp. For example 1461043742 this is today's timestamp, from that I want the timestamp of midnight 12'o clock timestamp value. And this is 1461130928 tomorrow's timestamp from this I want to show tomorrow midnight 12'o clock timestamp value. How can I do this, Is there any possibility to achieve this in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
// Input:
$now = 1461043742;

// Calculate:
$midnight = strtotime("midnight", $now);
$midnight_tomorrow = strtotime("midnight tomorrow", $now);

// Test
print(date('c', $midnight));
print(date('c', $midnight_tomorrow));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the hour and minute to the midnight hour.

```
$date = new DateTime() // By default gets the current time
$date.setTime(0,0,0) // Midnight hour
$stamp = date.getTimestamp()
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use strtotime

```
$date = '2016-04-18 00:00:00';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);

$date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
```